# C programming : Try to compile main class on terminal but it return me ./mainT

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to make input from command line argument. This is my code in c

```
int main(int argc,  char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    if (argc == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: You need an argument.\n");
        // We are out of here!
        return 1;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < argc; i += 1 )
    {
        char *pos = argv[0]; // pos is the pointer to the first position
        int possize = sizeof(argv[0]);
        for(i=0;i<possize;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",pos[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run it from terminal. I typed gcc main.c-o main and then ./main and it gave me ./mainT. Why it does that ? and can anyone  help me fix it please thank you.

Comment: Please post a cap off your terminal interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `argv[0]` contains always the string with which you called the program, so `argc` is always at least 1.

So the correct version is:

```
int main(int argc,  char * argv[]) {

    int i;
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("ERROR: You need an argument.\n");
        // We are out of here!
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all arguments
    for( i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
    {
        char *pos = argv[i];
        int possize = strlen(argv[i]);  //<-- use strlen here, not sizeof
        for(i=0;i<possize;i++)
        {
            printf("%c",pos[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that `sizeof(argv[0])` returns you the size of a pointer, not the
length of the string. You need `strlen` for that (see above in the corrected version).

On x86_64 systems a pointer has usually the size of 8, so `sizeof(argv[0])`
would return you 8. Because you executed the program with `./main`, the string
`"./main"` has a length of 6, hence your loop access memory out of bounds, which yields undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix two errors:

- `argv[0]` is not the first argument, it's the name of your program. If you want to print the initial command-line argument, use `argv[i]` instead, and make sure that you start `i` at `1`.
- `sizeof(argv[1])` is not going to yield the length of the parameter; use `strlen` instead.